# Rails omniauth more features

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth

I have followed this  [tutorial](https://richonrails.com/articles/facebook-authentication-in-ruby-on-rails)

And was able to complete facebook authentication .Now I need a way to fetch some information of a user from it like email,birthday ,username and all .Can any one give me some example of it .
[omniauth.rb]

```
OmniAuth.config.logger = Rails.logger

Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :facebook, 'my-app-id', 'my-app-key', {:client_options => {:ssl => {:ca_file => Rails.root.join("cacert.pem").to_s}}}

end
```

[user.rb]

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    def self.from_omniauth(auth)
  where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
    user.provider = auth.provider 
    user.uid      = auth.uid
    user.name     = auth.info.name
    user.save
  end
end

    def self.facebook
        @facebook ||=Koala::facebook::API.new(oauth_token)
    end
end
```

[application_controller]

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception


  helper_method :current_user

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
  end

end
```

[session_controller]

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    user = User.from_omniauth(env["omniauth.auth"])
    session[:user_id] = user.id
    redirect_to root_path
  end

  def destroy
    session[:user_id] = nil
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

Comment: Please add some code, on what have tried yet

Comment: I have updated my code

Comment: I am not getting oauth_token also I don't know how to display profile data